# Blender 2.79: Apply location snaps origin to the object's original location

Tags: origin

[image: Blender: Apply Location Problem]

Hi, I am encountering an issue in Blender 2.79 when I try to apply the location of an object. Every time I apply the location, the origin is reset to this random point off to the side. I'm guessing that I somehow stored data for the origin somewhere, but I don't know where. As you can hopefully see, using the Set Origin function works until I apply the location again. I don't have this problem with any other object, and I'm just not sure what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Well I think I very quickly answered my own question by just playing around with it a bit. I don't recall ever using it before, but apparently I applied the Location to Deltas for that object previously. To resolve, I repeated the process for the new origin location.

1. Set Origin > Origin to Geometry
2. CTRL+A > Location to Deltas

Hopefully this will help someone else who encounters this in the future. Cheers!